# Using the split within a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

> Simple function to capture the value of an array, separate by ":" and create a new array

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function sumArrayHours( arrayHr )
{
    var hr, min, hours;
    $.each(arrayHr, function(key, element) {
        hours = element.split(':');
        hr = parseInt(hours[0], 10);
        min = parseInt(hours[1], 10);
        console.log('hr: ' + key + ' ' + 'min: ' + element);
    });
}
var arrayHr = ["04:38", "05:49", "12:47"];
sumArrayHours( arrayHr );
```

> Is returning:
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Is in the penultimate line.

Comment: Seems works fine http://jsbin.com/raraha/1/edit?js,console

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/36wmsb68/ In the console: `hr: 0 min: 04:38,  hr: 1 min: 05:49, hr: 2 min: 12:47` No error

Comment: Strange, the application gave error. I'll try again. Thank U.

Comment: I found the error in one of the array record the value was undefined, so it did not work.